# How to find out the appropriate High Level Requirements?

Tags: requirements

Is there any official definition of high level requirements? I've searched google for a while but its still confusing me a lot.

I have a list of (Candidate) High Level Requirements.
And, I want to classify them as appropriate and inappropriate High Level Requirements. How can I do that? What criteria should I be checking against?

Comment: What are your criteria? What makes a requirement "appropriate" or "inappropriate"?

Comment: @CodeGnome, Do that base on the main purpose? Example: Create an application to manage an organization?

Comment: I'd say that instead of looking for a formal definition of what a High Level requirement means, you could understand how it'd be used within your context, tailoring it to your needs. Is it going to be used for estimates? For prioritization across other requirements? For onboarding of a book of work to a set of professionals? In each case, a 'High level requirement' would be different. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm just as confused as you are. Does high level requirement mean the requirements of upper management (high level) for reporting, accounting, etc. or the priority of the objectives of the project such as having an aesthetic building vs. functional or a certain level of increased productivity. After reading the stuff on google I have to assume it is the priority of the projects goals. But that isn't much different from the project scope. Your guess is as good as mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, *appropriate and inappropriate* are subjective categories, and as such, they won't help you start a conversation about the requirements. I would go with **does this requirement** - I'd ditch the high level as well - **help my customers achieve their goals?** If the answer is yes, you have a requirement, if no, you don't have.

For example, the requirement is to have a button for cancel on a web page. If you ask "how this button helps our customers to cancel our subscription?", you may conclude after a series of user interviews and A/B tests that they don't need a button, they are fine with a link. The first requirement was *inappropriate* using your terms, and the second was *appropriate*, and you figured out what to develop.